# Can Someone Normalize this table?

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I have this table to normalize for a uni project, now every time I think it should just
be two tables, I then think no it should be three... I am going to throw this out to one of you guys superior knowledge as maybe you can indicate the best way it should be done and why.

```
 Number Type    Single rate Double rate Family rate
1        D          56          72  
2        D          56          72  
3        T          50          72  
4        T          50          72  
5        S          48      
6        S          48      
7        S          48      
8        T          50          72  
9        T          50          72  
10       D          56          72  
11       D          56          72  
12       D          56          72  
13       D          56          72  
14       F          56          72         84
15       F          56          72         84
16       S          48      
17       S          48      
18       T          50          72  
20       D          56          72
```

Many thanks for anyone that can help me to see the corret way

Comment: This is not DoMyHomework.com

Comment: Why do you think it should be re-factored?

Comment: Also, technically, you cannot Normalize a design from data alone (that is, from mere *existential* relational cardinalities).  Although you may be able to eliminate the possibility of some relations, you cannot determine which of the remaining possible relations are the correct ones without knowing something about the meaning of the data and their various *potential* values.

Comment: Thank Rafael, I never asked to do my homework, I asked for pointers and help and if it was do my homework I would stick the other 8 xls files up, @ MIKE Cheel, if you are going by the rules of normalisation  then the rates are non depedant on the the primary key and should therefore be in their own table, but they are dependant on the type.

Comment: Ok my uderstanding of normalisation (I know that I am probably wrong here) is that you normalize each file on their own merits, then when all done look at the outcome

Comment: @RBarryYoung so would I be better to add all the data to one large flat file and normalize from there, in that way I would have an overview of all the data ?

Comment: @user2966477 Again, "*technically, you cannot Normalize a design from data alone.*"  You need to know something about the data's production, meaning and real-world relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to produce correct table design unless one understands exactly what the columns mean and how the data columns depend on one another. However, here is an attempt that can be refined once you provide more information for us. The used naming is not as good as I'd like it to be but as I said, the purpose is not clear in the question. Anyway, this is a start, hope it would help you.
Also note that Normalization is not always required for all types of applications. For example, Business Intelligence could use schema that are deliberately not fully normalized (e.g. Star Schema). So the database design may sometimes depend on the application nature and how data change.

```
Main 
----
MainID                      int           PK
MainTypeID                  Char(1)       Example: D, T, S etc.
MainRateIntersectionID      Int

MainRateIntersection
--------------------
MainRateIntersectionID      int           PK
MainID                      int
RateCategoryID              int


The combination of MainID and RateCategoryID should be constrained 
using UNIQUE INDEX

RateCategory
------------
RateCategoryID              int            PK
RateCategoryText            Varchar2(15)   Not Null    Example:Single, Family, etc.
RateValue                   Int            Nullable

MainType
---------
MainTypeID      Char(1)     PK
```

## Edit

Based on the new information, I have revised the model. I have removed the 'artificial' IDs since this is a training project for Normalization. Artificial IDs (surrogate keys) are correct to add but is not your objective as I guess. I have to add booking table that where a row would be inserted for each customer that makes a booking. You need to add appropriate customer information in that table. The table you provided is more of a logical view that could be returned form a query but not a physical table to store and update in the database. Instead, the bookings table should be used.

I hope this could help you.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, lets see if I can try and make you aware of what it relates to. The table relates to a booking system for a hotel, That I imagine would have the follwing headings Room_ID, TYPE, then the room rates depend on the the room type that depends on the Room_ID etc. When I spoke to my leturer regarding the normalisation he said that I can only normalise one table a time, which I found strange as I need to know what relation it has to the other tables, but was told this was the correct way.

Comment: OK, this is good info. I will get back with you after a while to provide a more accurate version based on your feedback.

Comment: WOW thanks Emmad, you have went above and beyond what is required, many thanks again only helping me out with this solution.

Comment: No problem, this is just a first thought, please let me know if you have questions.